# How to pass a Julia type in the R package JuliaConnectoR

Tags: r, types, julia

I try to use the R package `JuliaConnectoR` to work with the Julia package `EvoTrees`.
I see how I can pass numerical paramters defined in R to Julia (e.g., a double is translated to Float64), but I can't see how I can define a paramter in R that describes a type in Julia.

The following is an example:

```
n_obs = 100 
n_features = 100
nrounds = 10L

set.seed(20221224)

x_train = matrix(ncol= n_features, rnorm(n_obs*n_features))
y_train = rnorm(n_obs)

library(JuliaConnectoR)
evoTrees = juliaImport("EvoTrees")
params_evo = evoTrees$EvoTreeRegressor(nrounds=nrounds , loss = as.symbol("linear"), alpha=0.5,lambda=0.0,gamma=0.0)

evoTrees_model = evoTrees$fit_evotree(params_evo, x_train, y_train, print_every_n = 50L)
```

The call to `evoTrees$EvoTreeRegressor` works fine I e..g., can pass the julia symbol `:linear` by `as.symbol("linear")` and passing numerical parameters like `nrounds` is clear too. However, I get the following error message for the call of the fit `evoTrees$fit_evotree`:

> Error: Evaluation in Julia failed. Original Julia error message:
> MethodError: no method matching
> fit_evotree(::EvoTrees.EvoTreeRegressor{EvoTrees.Linear, Float32},
> ::Matrix{Float64}, ::Vector{Float64}; print_every_n=50) Closest
> candidates are:   fit_evotree(::Union{EvoTrees.EvoTreeClassifier{L,
> T}, EvoTrees.EvoTreeCount{L, T}, EvoTrees.EvoTreeGaussian{L, T},
> EvoTrees.EvoTreeMLE{L, T}, EvoTrees.EvoTreeRegressor{L, T}}; x_train,
> y_train, w_train, offset_train, x_eval, y_eval, w_eval, offset_eval,
> metric, early_stopping_rounds, print_every_n, verbosity, fnames,
> return_logger) where {L, T} at
> C:\Users\rwarn.julia\packages\EvoTrees\ayRL8\src\fit.jl:309
> Stacktrace:  [1] invokelatest(::Any, ::Any, ::Vararg{Any};
> kwargs::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Int64, Tuple{Symbol},
> NamedTuple{(:print_every_n,), Tuple{Int64}}})    @ Base
> .\essentials.jl:731  [2] evaluate!(call::Main.RConnector.Call,
> communicator::Main.RConnector.CommunicatoR{Sockets.TCPSocket})    @
> Main.RConnector C:\Users\rwarn\Documents\R\win-l

I interpret this error as follows: Without passing a type via the Julia parameter `T`, data types of Float32 are assumed. However, the train data in R type double is translated to Julia type Float64.
I think, the solution would be to pass a the Julia type Float64 to `evoTrees$EvoTreeRegressor`. How can I do that? Thank you!

Infos:
JuliaConnectoR: v1.1.1
EvoTrees v0.14.2

> sessionInfo() R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build
> 22621)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=German_Austria.1252
> LC_CTYPE=German_Austria.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Austria.1252 [4]
> LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Austria.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
> datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] JuliaConnectoR_1.1.1
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] compiler_4.1.1
> tictoc_1.0.1   tools_4.1.1

Comment: *the train data in R type double is translated to Julia type Float64*. But I don't see any `double` in your code.

Comment: What I mean is that train data is of type double in R. The question is, how to define a type parameter T with the value Float64 to tell evotrees that data is in Float64. As I understand it, a type is itself a type in Julia (T) and I would like to set it via juliaconnectoR. Thank you!

Comment: I got you at the beginning. But I thought you should use a function like `double` to convert the object's type (Sorry, I'm not familiar with R).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right, the default type that is assumed is `Float32`. It can be seen in the code [here](https://github.com/Evovest/EvoTrees.jl/blob/7c989bb03863e951ee8ba8233460f18584f45d53/src/models.jl#L51).

The constructor also accepts the keyword argument `T` for defining the type.
If you want to pass the Julia type `Float64` as a value for this argument, you can do this like shown below:

```
params_evo = evoTrees$EvoTreeRegressor(T = juliaExpr("Float64"), 
    rounds=nrounds, loss = as.symbol("linear"), alpha=0.5, lambda=0.0, gamma=0.0)
```

The `juliaExpr` function of the `JuliaConnectoR` allows to use arbitrary Julia expressions in calls from R.
The expressions are evaluated in Julia and the resulting values are used in this place.
This is useful for situations like this where an argument of a function cannot be expressed properly in R.

An alternative to this is using the `juliaEval` function, which will give the same output as `juliaExpr` in this case, but will make a round trip from Julia to R before making the function call.

The created `EvoTreeRegressor` object now uses the Julia `Float64` type:

```
> params_evo
<Julia object of type EvoTrees.EvoTreeRegressor{EvoTrees.Linear, Float64}>
EvoTrees.EvoTreeRegressor{EvoTrees.Linear, Float64}(10, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 5, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 32, 0.5, Dict{Int64, Int64}(), Random.TaskLocalRNG(), "cpu")
```

Comment: Thank you, `juliaExpr` was the solution :)